# Print a matrix without row and column indices

Tags: r, matrix, printing, indices

If I print a matrix, it is shown with row and column indices in the console. E.g.

```
> print(diag(3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

How can I suppress the column and row indices? I.e. something like this:

```
> print(diag(3), indices=FALSE)
1    0    0
0    1    0
0    0    1
```

I can see that the `cwhmisc` package should contain a `printM` function to do this [according to the documentation](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/cwhmisc/html/prinq.html) but it is not there when I load cwhmisc. Also, this seems like something you should be able to to in base R.

Comment: Question: **Why** do you want to do this? Printing to the console is purely for operational use; if you want the matrix "printed" to a file, there are plenty of options in things like `write.table` to suppress row and column names.

Comment: Answer: To quickly copy the matrix (actually a ``as.matrix(tabular(...))``) to a paper draft without having to write/open/copy/close files and without having to manually remove the indices. Just laziness, I guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function [`prmatrix`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/prmatrix) in the `base` package could work for this, it can take the arguments `collab` and `rowlab`:

```
prmatrix(diag(3), rowlab=rep("",3), collab=rep("",3))

 1 0 0
 0 1 0
 0 0 1
```

Comment: (+1) It's funny that it is the example in the documentation :)

Comment: This adds space at the top and the left side though. The output is the same as for `m <- diag(3); colnames(m) <- rownames(m) <- rep("", 3); print(m)`.

Comment: The documentation seems to be out of date: it references `print.matrix` but there doesn't appear to be any such print method in current R versions.

Comment: Thanks! I chose this answer over ``write.table`` because it keeps columns aligned and I do have characters in my matrix. Manually specifying ``rowlab`` and ``collab`` is ugly though and I tried out ``write.table`` in combination with ``print(...., gap=3)`` for this reason but couldn't get it to work. Using ``prmatrix(my_matrix, rowlab=rep("", nrow(my_matrix), collab=rep("", ncol(my_matrix))`` is nicer for future copy-and-paste :-) You're welcome to update your answer with this.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution with function `write.table`

```
write.table(diag(3), row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

You can make it prettier by separating the columns with a tabulation

```
write.table(matrix(sample(1000,9),3,3), row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t")
```