# R rbind command remove extra information

Tags: r, rbind

```
x=rbind(rep(1:3),rep(1:3))
x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
```

How is it possible to remove the braces and values inside with comma? I try make.row.names = FALSE but this does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906557/print-a-matrix-without-row-and-column-indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `rownames` and `colnames`:

```
colnames(x) <- 1:3
rownames(x) <- 1:2
x
#  1 2 3
#1 1 2 3
#2 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably confusing matrices with data frames?

```
x <- rbind(rep(1:3), rep(1:3))
x
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
```

The display is perfectly fine, since `x` is a matrix:

```
class(x)
# [1] "matrix"
```

You could change `dimnames` like so

```
dimnames(x) <- list(1:nrow(x), 1:ncol(x))
x
#   1 2 3
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 1 2 3
```

However, probably you want a data frame.

```
x <- as.data.frame(rbind(rep(1:3), rep(1:3)))
x
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  1  2  3

class(x)
# [1] "data.frame"
```